# Put elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem. I'm trying put some images side by side each other, so it looks like a portfolio. What would be the best way to implement this. Thank you in advance. You can refer to the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cntra/E7Ydz/

This [HTML] is a follows:

```
<div id="portfolio" style="height: 3020px;">

 <div id="project" class="cms design html-css " data-col="1" data-row="0" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry1" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/work_thumbnail275.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/jane-stockdale/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
                </div>
            <div id="workTags">


            </div>
      </div>
    </div>


          <div id="project" class="design illustration html-css " data-col="2" data-row="0" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry2" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/work_thumbnail2.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/street-child-world-cup-i-am-somebody/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
      </div>
            <div id="workTags">                 

            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          <div id="project" class="app database design " data-col="0" data-row="1" style="right: 0px; opacity: 1; top: 0px;">
    <div id="workEntry3" class="workEntry">

       <div id="thumbAttachment">
                    <div id="inThumb">
                    <img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/files_mf/pgtips_thumb37.jpg">
        </div>

         <div id="blackCross"> <a href="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/pg-tips-vs-january/"><img src="http://www.enjoythis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/enjoyThis/images/thumb_transparency.png"></a></div>

          </div>


        <!--<div id="attachmentShadowThumb"></div>-->


        <div id="workTitle">
        </div>
            <div id="workTags">


            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the [css]:

```
#project{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
    height:250px;
    width:325px;
    display: inline;
}

.workEntry{ 
    width:310px;
    overflow:hidden;
}



#thumbAttachment{
    float:left;
    width: 310px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inThumb{
    float:left;
}

#blackCross{
    float:left;
    width: 310px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    khtml-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;

}

#blackCross:visited{

    khtml-opacity:0;
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
}

#blackCross:hover{
    khtml-opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=100)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the width of div.project to be 325px but the images are only 310px.

http://jsfiddle.net/E7Ydz/2/

```
#project{
float:left;
position:relative;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
height:200px;
width:309px;
display: inline;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

```
.workEntry{ 
    width:310px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;//make each element float left
}

#project{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0px; //no padding should be here
    height:250px;
    width:310px;//should be same size as .workEntry
    display: inline;
    overflow:hidden;//trick to ensure all elements fit in portfolio
}
```

you could also put this at the end of the list of work entries to stop following elements from getting out of line:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't fixed it.

Comment: i'm using google chrome and the fiddle works for me. What error are you getting? and what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome also. I've just noticed I nay have wrote the question incorrect. I wanted them to to be side by side without no space.

Comment: fixed it, the #project style shouldn't have a 'float:left'